# R - repeated execution of a script

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have an R script that makes certain twitter searches and adds the results, along with a timestamp, to a data frame. What I would like is a way to schedule this script to run every, say, five minutes. Is there a way to do this within R?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solely about the use of R. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for advice on software-related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a Linux machine you can use cron jobs ([link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)) on Windows based machines there is a utility called Task Scheduler ([link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Scheduler)) which can be used. With those you can call `RScript` which allows you to execute an R script from the command line (older versions of R on Linux might require you to use `R CMD`, if so I suggest updating your R). Here is the help from `Rscript`:

```
Usage: /path/to/Rscript [--options] [-e expr] file [args]

--options accepted are
  --help              Print usage and exit
  --version           Print version and exit
  --verbose           Print information on progress
  --default-packages=list
                      Where 'list' is a comma-separated set
                        of package names, or 'NULL'
or options to R, in addition to --slave --no-restore, such as
  --save              Do save workspace at the end of the session
  --no-environ        Don't read the site and user environment files
  --no-site-file      Don't read the site-wide Rprofile
  --no-init-file      Don't read the user R profile
  --restore           Do restore previously saved objects at startup
  --vanilla           Combine --no-save, --no-restore, --no-site-file
                        --no-init-file and --no-environ

'file' may contain spaces but not shell metacharacters
```

The package [tcltk2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tcltk2/tcltk2.pdf) also allows you to schedule tasks from a running R console using `tclTask`. So that too is something to consider.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was an in-R solution, since the timeframes are pretty small and I am not quite used to think of cron for tasks that you want to repeat every few seconds! Still, very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `Sys.sleep(time)` in a loop or check the actual time with `Sys.time` in a loop if you want to rely on R code.